# Custom deque(double ended queue) class.

Tags: c++, queue, deque

This is my first time in building a custom deque(Double Ended Queue) class in c++ .This code is giving me Multiple definition error for head and tail.What should i do? what changes should be made?

// this is the header file(dequeue.h)

```
        #ifndef DEQUEUE_H
#define DEQUEUE_H
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
/*
 * Node Declaration
 */
struct node
{
    int info;
    node *next;
    node *prev;

}*head, *tail;

class dequeue
{
    public:
        int top1, top2;
        void insert();
        void del();
        void display();
        dequeue()
        {
            top1 = 0;
            top2 = 0;
            head = NULL;
            tail = NULL;
        }
};

#endif // DEQUEUE_H
```

//This is the dequeue.cpp file

```
#include "dequeue.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;


/*
 * Insert Element in Doubly Ended Queue
 */
void dequeue::insert()
{
    struct node *temp;
    int ch, value;
    if (top1 + top2 >= 50)
    {
        cout<<"Dequeue Overflow"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    if (top1 + top2 == 0)
    {
        cout<<"Enter the value to be inserted: ";
        cin>>value;
        head = new (struct node);
        head->info = value;
        head->next = NULL;
        head->prev = NULL;
        tail = head;
        top1++;
        cout<<"Element Inserted into empty deque"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        while (1)
        {
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"1.Insert Element at first"<<endl;
            cout<<"2.Insert Element at last"<<endl;
            cout<<"3.Exit"<<endl;
            cout<<endl;
            cout<<"Enter Your Choice: ";
            cin>>ch;
            cout<<endl;
            switch(ch)
            {
            case 1:
                cout<<"Enter the value to be inserted: ";
                cin>>value;
                temp = new (struct node);
                temp->info = value;
                temp->next = head;
                temp->prev = NULL;
                head->prev = temp;
                head = temp;
                top1++;
                break;
            case 2:
                cout<<"Enter the value to be inserted: ";
                cin>>value;
                temp = new (struct node);
                temp->info = value;
                temp->next = NULL;
                temp->prev = tail;
                tail->next = temp;
                tail = temp;
                top2++;
                break;
            case 3:
                return;
                break;
            default:
                cout<<"Wrong Choice"<<endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Delete Element in Doubly Ended Queue
 */
void dequeue::del()
{
    if (top1 + top2 <= 0)
    {
        cout<<"Deque Underflow"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    int ch;
    while (1)
    {
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Delete Element at first"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Delete Element at last"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter Your Choice: ";
        cin>>ch;
        cout<<endl;
        switch(ch)
        {
        case 1:
            head = head->next;
            head->prev = NULL;
            top1--;
            break;
        case 2:
            tail = tail->prev;
            tail->next = NULL;
            top2--;
            break;
        case 3:
            return;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Wrong Choice"<<endl;
        }
    }
}

/*
 * Display Doubly Ended Queue
 */
void dequeue::display()
{
    struct node *temp;
    int ch;
    if (top1 + top2 <= 0)
    {
        cout<<"Deque Underflow"<<endl;
        return;
    }
    while (1)
    {
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Display Deque from Beginning"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Display Deque from End"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Exit"<<endl;
        cout<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter Your Choice: ";
        cin>>ch;
        cout<<endl;
        switch (ch)
        {
        case 1:
            temp = head;
            cout<<"Deque from Beginning:"<<endl;
            while (temp != NULL)
            {
                cout<<temp->info<<" ";
                temp = temp->next;
            }
            cout<<endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout<<"Deque from End:"<<endl;
            temp = tail;
            while (temp != NULL)
            {
                cout<<temp->info<<" ";
                temp = temp->prev;
            }
            temp = tail;
            cout<<endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            return;
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Wrong Choice"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
```

//This the main.cpp`#include

```
#include "dequeue.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int choice;
    dequeue dl;
    while (1)
    {
        cout<<"\n-------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"Operations on Deque"<<endl;
        cout<<"\n-------------"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Insert Element into the Deque"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Delete Element from the Deque"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Traverse the Deque"<<endl;
        cout<<"4.Quit"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter your Choice: ";
        cin>>choice;
        cout<<endl;
        switch(choice)
        {
        case 1:
            dl.insert();
            break;
        case 2:
            dl.del();
            break;
        case 3:
            dl.display();
            break;
        case 4:
            exit(1);
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"Wrong Choice"<<endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

`
```

Comment: Suggestion: just use `std::deque`.

Answer (score 2):

The `head` and `tail` variables will be defined everywhere you include the dequeue.h file.

Did you mean for them to be class members of `dequeue`?

If you really to share them, move them to the cpp file and declare them `extern` in the h file.

Comment: I hope he does mean for them to be class members... terrible design otherwise!

Comment: yes, i wanted them to be class members. how do i declare them?

Comment: Put `node *head, *tail;` in your class definition.